# How to select a rotating Hydra option?

Tags: spacemacs, ivy, hydra

From SPC f f (counsel-find-file) minibuffer, open Hydra with C-o (hydra-ivy/body).
This is what hydra looks on my system:
[image]

The Hydra right column has "[m] matcher: order".
Pressing 'm' rotates matcher between "other" and "ivy".
How to active "other" or "ivy"?
Why does "order" not appear in the rotation?

Some of the Hydra commands in the menu are not obvious (not to me).
Where are the Hydra commands documented?

I am using Emacs 26.1 with Evil Spacemacs 0.200.13 and Ivy.

UPDATE 1:

The screenshot of my Hydra matches the Spacemacs Hydra documentation at:
https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/c7a103a772d808101d7635ec10f292ab9202d9ee/layers/%2Bspacemacs/spacemacs-completion/packages.el > define-transient-state ivy

Seems that my:

- Hydra menu is for Spacemacs mode
- Hydra is not running Spacemacs mode
- Hydra *help* does not describe Hydra Spacemacs mode

Three examples follow.

1) Hydra menu says:

```
[f] case-fold: auto
```

Pressing 'f' toggles between 'nil' and 'auto'.
In the help, hydra-ivy/body says:

```
"f": ‘ivy-alt-done &optional’
Exit the minibuffer with the selected candidate.
```

2) Hydra menu says:

```
[TAB] alt done
```

Pressing TAB opens *ivy-occur counsel-find-file ""*<2> like this:
[image]
In the help, hydra-ivy/body does not mention "TAB".

3) Hydra menu says:

```
[c] & cont
```

Pressing 'c' opens *ivy-occur counsel-find-file ""*<2>.
In the help, hydra-ivy/body says:

```
"c":    ‘ivy-toggle-calling’
```

UPDATE 2:

posted issue: [Hydra key behaviors do not match the Hydra menu in Spacemacs.](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/2041)

UPDATE 3:

From C-h f hydra-ivy/body RET:

```
hydra-ivy/body is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
‘ivy-hydra.el’.

(hydra-ivy/body)

Call the body in the "hydra-ivy" hydra.

The heads for the associated hydra are:

"h":    ‘ivy-beginning-of-buffer’,
"j":    ‘ivy-next-line’,
"k":    ‘ivy-previous-line’,
"l":    ‘ivy-end-of-buffer’,
"o":    ‘keyboard-escape-quit’,
"C-g":    ‘keyboard-escape-quit’,
"i":    ‘nil’,
"C-o":    ‘nil’,
"f":    ‘ivy-alt-done’,
"C-j":    ‘ivy-alt-done’,
"d":    ‘ivy-done’,
"g":    ‘ivy-call’,
"C-m":    ‘ivy-done’,
"c":    ‘ivy-toggle-calling’,
"m":    ‘ivy-rotate-preferred-builders’,
">":    ‘ivy-minibuffer-grow’,
"<":    ‘ivy-minibuffer-shrink’,
"w":    ‘ivy-prev-action’,
"s":    ‘ivy-next-action’,
"a":    ‘ivy-read-action’,
"t":    ‘(setq truncate-lines (not truncate-lines))’,
"C":    ‘ivy-toggle-case-fold’,
"u":    ‘ivy-occur’,
"D":    ‘(ivy-exit-with-action (lambda (_) (find-function (quote hydra-ivy/body))))’

The body can be accessed via ‘hydra-ivy/body’.
```

Comment: By "Where are the Hydra commands documented?" you mean hydra in general or this particular hydra-ivy commands. I find the documentation on the github pages of ivy and hydra quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case `hydra-ivy` looks a bit different but one can see that here `&` is just a part of the description of the command being executed. The commands themselves are the usual ivy commands.

For instance `[RET]` will call `ivy-done` and I guess that `[i]` will close the hydra and insert the current match into the minibuffer while `[q]` will just close the hydra.

I suggest looking at the definition of `hydra-ivy`, i.e. `C-h f hydra-ivy/body RET`.

**EDIT:** After the update of the question it looks to me as if you have a clash of two versions because the actual commands do not match with their description. Your hydra seems to be defined [here on the Spacemacs github](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/c7a103a772d808101d7635ec10f292ab9202d9ee/layers/%2Bspacemacs/spacemacs-completion/packages.el) There you can see which commands by which keys and look up the corresponding commands via `C-h f`.

Comment: I looked at hydra-ivy/body help.  Details in the main question under UPDATE 1.

Comment: Updatet the answer

Comment: I will install the next version of Emacs when it is released in the dnf package managerer, which is in 6 months.  In the meantime, should I submit a bug report?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it is a bug in swiper because the hydra you are using is not from that repo. What does `C-h f hydra-ivy/body RET` show you? Are the packages swiper, ivy, ivy-hydra also installed from melpa?

Comment: I added "C-h f hydra-ivy/body RET" results to main question's UPDATE 3.  Not sure about melpa, this is in my .spacemacs file: (require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(package-initialize)

Comment: Your `C-h f` result is the one from the "original" hydra-ivy, but the hydra-ivy in the screenshot is from spacemacs which for some reason seems to override the function but not its documentation. So this is not an issue of swiper.

Comment: I submitted the issue at https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/12231

Answer (score 1):

I posted on your Spacemacs issue as well, but thought I'd share my answer here too.

The issue here is that the hydra you are viewing when pressing `C-o` is **not** the Ivy hydra. It is a custom hydra set by `spacemacs|define-transient-state` in the `spacemacs-completion` layer that @andrej mentioned.

When you press `C-o` while in an Ivy buffer in Spacemacs, it actually calls the function `spacemacs/ivy-transient-state/body`, and those are the bindings you are seeing in the menu.

If you want to launch the normal `hydra-ivy/body` menu, that is mapped to `M-SPC` in the Spacemacs Ivy layer.

If you want to map `C-o` to open the standard Ivy hydra, that is certainly doable. But the root cause here is that you are not actually viewing the `hydra-ivy/body` menu, so the Emacs function help doesn't match up.